# Tip selection can be done by myself?

Tags: tip-selection, tips

I've read the documentation about the lazy Tips and why you should use these algorithms in order to get the "best" Tips. But I have a question: is possible to choose by myself what tips refer to? And, more specifically, is possible to select a parent to which refer to, that is not a Tip?
Thanks